# ACF link to button in woocommerce single page

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am struggling to add a acf URL field to a button in woo single page.
Any help?

This is what I have so far.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'display_acf_field_under_cart' );
/*
 * Content below "Add to cart" Button.
 */
function display_acf_field_under_cart() {

  echo '<div>

  <a href=" the_field("button_url"); "><button class="gc-outline">Tested button</button></a>

  </div>';
}
```

However it is not working....

Thanks

Comment: You should use `<a href="' . get_field("button_url") . '">` instead of  `<a href=" the_field("button_url"); ">` to get your code working…

Answer (score 0):

@LoicTheAztec comment can help you achieve your goal because it corrects a `php` error in your code.

But to go further I added a condition as shown in [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) so that you won't show an empty button if `button_url` field is empty for a product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'display_acf_field_under_cart' );
/*
 * Content below "Add to cart" Button.
 */
function display_acf_field_under_cart() {
$button_url = get_field('button_url');
if ($button_url) {
  echo '<div>
  <a href="'.$button_url.'"><button class="gc-outline">Tested button</button></a>
  </div>';
  }else {
    echo '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm! Will keep in mind the if and else.